# Launch .out file from python script when a button is pressed in Raspberry

Tags: permissions, raspberry-pi

I am connected to a Raspberry Pi using ssh and I have got a python script that lauches a file .out when a button is pressed. The point is that I can access this python file pressing the button but it shows the following error when tries to execute the command in system:

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

def play(channel):
        os.system('./a.out')

GPIO.add_event_detect(24, GPIO.RISING, callback = play, bouncetime = 3000)

while 1:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Here is the error:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
(focus:2532): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: localhost:10.0
```

Thank you